# Filename in android rejected by ffmpeg command

Tags: android, android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Planning to use ffmpeg in Android for A/V conversion. Installed Android Studio 3.5.3.  I am fairly new to Android development and the folder names, unlike in windows system, is fairly confusing to me. I am able to build the gradle without any error but the fetched pathname is rejected by ffmpeg commandline.

**Questions:**

1) Resulting path_name shows both pathname and filename which is cool. Is the resulting path_name correct or expected? However, ffmpeg raised error flag citing that directory/file do not exist corresponding to the resulting path_name.

2) Inside android properties, the path starts with "Device storage/..." but Android Studio command starts with "/document/". Why I see this variation?

3) `onActivityResult()` do not work with  `@override private` prefix but works with `@override public`, is it expected? Many examples on internet, however use private though.

4)  `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` code do not work at all, is it deprecated in Android 3.5.5?

**Java code:**

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 7 &&  resultCode == RESULT_OK){    
                    path_name = data.getData().getPath();    
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

```
path_name = "/document/primary:WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/AUD-20200402-WA0006.mp3" **strong text**
```

Comment: You probably have to escape the `:` and spaces. You should provide the actual error from `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @llogan :In the commandline, I observed, whitespaces are allowed if path is declared within ". Is "-" the culprit?

Comment: @seccpur I don't know anything about Android, but I'll guess that `-` shouldn't be a problem as I doubt it is considered to be a special character.

Answer (score 0):

Old PATH:

```
path_name = "/document/primary:WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/AUD-20200402-WA0006.mp3"
```

Rename the file name and remove " - " this symbol.

Example (NEW PATH):

```
path_name = "/document/primary:WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/audiofile.mp3"
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I  tried with a simple filename without special characters, but still error persist. Inside android properties, the path starts with "Device storage/...".